# How to reference Sprite object property in one class from another?

Tags: python, livewires

I dont know how to reference the 'top' property of the Sprite object in Livewires in one class, from another class??

Comment: give us some code we can look at.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Sprite` is the class you dealing with...

This is how you access an object attribute:

```
>>> a = Sprite()
>>> a.top
```

This is how you access a class attribute:

```
>>> Sprite.top
```

Is this what you're looking for?